# can't animate over a loop in an animation block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"INDEX %d",  index);

            [self.visibleViewControllers_ enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {                                 
                UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)obj;
                if (viewController.view.tag != index){
                    if (viewController.view.tag < index){
                        NSLog(@"LOWER VIEW WITH TAG %d", viewController.view.tag);
                        [viewController.view setFrameY:self.contentOffset.y - viewController.view.frameHeight];
                    } else if (viewController.view.tag > index){
                        NSLog(@"UPPER VIEW WITH TAG %d", viewController.view.tag);
                        [viewController.view setFrameY:600];
                    } else {
                        [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentOffset.y, selectedView.frameWidth, 460)];
                    }
                }
            }];
            //[selectedView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentOffset.y, selectedView.frameWidth, 460)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [self.visibleViewControllers_ enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {                                 
                UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)obj;
                NSLog(@"VIEW CONTROLLER Y IS %f AT INDEX %d", viewController.view.frameY, viewController.view.tag);
            }];

        }];
```

Basically it's a dictionary of view controllers that it's view I want to animate, but what's weird is that it only performs one animation. Not all. Why is this? Is it possible to do enumeration inside an animation block?

Comment: what is the output of all the log messages?

Comment: log message is outputing just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enumerate your views and animate them in your enumeration

```
[self.visibleViewControllers_ enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^
    [UIView animation.....
```

you did one animation and enumerate all view in this animation. just turn it around

Comment: that's what I am doing above.. isn't it

Comment: I am setting all of the view controller and setting it's view's to a final point where I wait it

Comment: if I do it like that then the animation won't happen at the same time, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: i think there shouldnt be any problems. just try it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
- (void) startAnimationLoop {
    keyIndex = 0;
    keysToLoopThrough = [self.visibleViewControllers_ allKeys];
    [self animate];
}

- (void) animate {
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.visibleViewControllers_ objectForKey:[keysToLoopThrough objectAtIndex:keyIndex]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            if (viewController.view.tag != index){
                if (viewController.view.tag < index){
                    NSLog(@"LOWER VIEW WITH TAG %d", viewController.view.tag);
                    [viewController.view setFrameY:self.contentOffset.y - viewController.view.frameHeight];
                } else if (viewController.view.tag > index){
                    NSLog(@"UPPER VIEW WITH TAG %d", viewController.view.tag);
                    [viewController.view setFrameY:600];
                } else {
                    [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentOffset.y, selectedView.frameWidth, 460)];
                }
             }
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            keyIndex++;
            if (keyIndex < [keysToLoopThrough count])
                [self animate];
            else NSLog("Finished");
        }];
}
```